# How to get onTextChanged for a edittext promptsView

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I am using an edittext as promptview to get input from user. But It do not seem that onTextChanged is called when user enters input to edit text. 
How can I get onTextChanged to get called.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_write, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("OK",new 
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
final EditText mTextView = (EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.userinput);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
    //do your code
}
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            Log.e("textwatcher", "afterTextChanged:\t" +s.toString());
        }
    });
```